# How to use multiple progress bars next to each other with the same progress?

Tags: c#, math, progress-bar

For example, I have 3 progress bars next to each other in a 'progress bar group'. If I set the progress bar group's progress to 50%, the first progress bar will be full, the second progress bar will be half full, and the third progress bar will be unchanged.

I know that this has something to do with math and fractions, but I've been racking my head over this for hours and I can't figure out a good way of doing this.

The details I gave above isn't actually my real problem, it's just there to help understand my situation better. Here's the real thing:

[image: 3 progress bars stacked upon each other]

So you can probably get what I'm trying to do now by looking at that image.  If you happen to have some code lying around for this, please share it. If you don't, then don't waste your time on me and just tell me the general idea instead.

Comment: Set the `Maximum` of `[1]` to 33, `Maximum` of `[2]` to 33, `Maximum` of `[3]` to 34. When the progress is < 34, update `[1]`, between 34 and 66 update `[2]`, above 66, `[3]`. The scale depends on how you're calculating the percentage in relation to the file size. The chunk size could be `[ChunkSize] = [FileLength] / 100` =>  `[Percentage] = [TotalDownloaded] / [ChunkSize]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a class that might work for you:

```
public class JoinedProgressBar
{
    private List<ProgressBar> _progressBars;

    public JoinedProgressBar(List<ProgressBar> progressBars)
    {
        _progressBars = progressBars ?? new List<ProgressBar>();
    }

    public void UpdateBarsPercent(int value)
    {
        UpdateBars(value * GetSum() / 100);
    }

    public void UpdateBars(int value)
    {
        var remaining = value;

        for(int i = 0; i < _progressBars.Count; i++)
        {
            _progressBars[i].Value = 
                remaining <= _progressBars[i].Minimum ? _progressBars[i].Minimum :
                remaining >= _progressBars[i].Maximum ? _progressBars[i].Maximum : remaining;

            remaining -= _progressBars[i].Maximum;
        }
    }

    public int GetSum()
    {
        var bars = _progressBars.Select(pb => pb.Maximum).ToList();
        return bars.Count > 0 ? bars.Sum() : 0;
    }

    public void SetOverallMaximum(int maximum)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _progressBars.Count; i++)
        {
            _progressBars[i].Minimum = 0;
            _progressBars[i].Maximum = maximum / _progressBars.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
        var jpb = new JoinedProgressBar(new List<ProgressBar>() { progressBar1, progressBar2, progressBar3 });

        for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i += 10)
        { 
            jpb.UpdateBarsPercent(i);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
```